# momentum and inelastic collisions

Tags: collision

I have two bodies with mass of $A >B$ , these start from the endpoint of a straight line path and move towards each each other with a constant velocity $v$ , so that they collide for time $t$ ,

so here come in the questions

1. Will there ever be a situation where both $A$ and $B$ come to rest ? Well i dont think that will happen because else law of conservation of momentum will not hold
2. Is it correct to think of exchange of momentum (gaining and losing of momentum on different bodies) , as an exchange of energy ?
3. If the answer to question 2 is yes then there would not be any diffuculties when we are thinking about conservation of momentum in elastic bodies , but in inelastic colliions as some of the energy goes into deformation and other stuff , only a part of energy goes into acceleration ? is that true ?

Comment: A fairly standard homework question?

Comment: @Farcher
well ,that was not a homework question!

Comment: Hi Faiz Iqbal. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of the masses must come to rest if one or both of the masses change direction.
The system of two masses has a centre of mass with linear momentum $m_A u - m_B u$ in the direction of $A$'s travel before the collision.
Since there are no external forces acting that momentum cannot change and so there must always be parts of those masses which are moving.

The transfer of momentum will impart on the change in kinetic energy of the two masses but energy and momentum are very different beasts.  For example energy is always conserved that is not true of momentum.

You must not mix your concepts eg only a part of energy goes into acceleration.

In an elastic collision with no external forces acting momentum and kinetic energy are conserved.

In a non elastic collision with no external forces acting momentum is conserved but kinetic energy is not.

The acceleration etc will depend on other factors, eg the time over which the collision took place.